# How to hide "enable auto-updates" link on Wordpress Installed Plugins page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have modified a Wordpress plugin which should not be auto updated later. So in order to prevent any admin from mistakenly clicking the "enable auto-updates" link on the installed plugins page, I want to hide it. I have seen some of the pro/premium/nulled plugins doing this but couldn't find a workaround. How can I remove that link for a particular plugin?

[image]

Added the following code to the plugin's main php file (plugins/example-plugin/example-plugin.php) but still the link shows on the installed plugins page.

```
add_filter( 'http_request_args', 'dm_prevent_update_check', 10, 2 );
function dm_prevent_update_check( $r, $url ) {
    if ( 0 === strpos( $url, 'http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/' ) ) {
        $my_plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
        $plugins = unserialize( $r['body']['plugins'] );
        unset( $plugins->plugins[$my_plugin] );
        unset( $plugins->active[array_search( $my_plugin, $plugins->active )] );
        $r['body']['plugins'] = serialize( $plugins );
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the updates by adding this code into your functions.php file of theme.

remove_action( 'load-update-core.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );

add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_plugins', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

Comment: This removes "Enable/disable auto-updates" links of all plugins. I want to remove this link of a specific plugin.